# Problema para vincular un Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

Tengo un problema para vincular un observable que creo en un servicio con una variable de un componente.

Aquí esta el código:

servicio1.ts

```
private myObservable$ = new Subject<myInterface>();
    constructor() { 
      this.crearObservable$();
    }

nuevoObjeto(dato1: string, dato2: string): myInterface {
    return {
    datoUno: dato1,
    datoDos: dato2,
    };
}

crearObservable$() {
    let observableAUX: myInterface;
    observableAUX = this.nuevoUsuario("Dato 1", "Dato 2");
    this.myObservable$.next(observableAUX);
}

getObservable$(): Observable<myInterface> {
    return this.myObservable$.asObservable();
}
```

componente1.ts

```
datos: Observable<myInterface>;
datos: Usuario;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.datos$ = this.servicio1.getObservable$();
    this.datos$.subscribe(datos => this.datos = datos);
    console.log(this.datos);
}
```

Por supuesto tanto el servicio como el interface esta importado en nada sitio.

Pero por alguna razón `this.datos` no pilla los valores.

Agradecería vuestra ayuda.

Gracias de Antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema era como decía Pablo Lozano que debía suscribir antes de emitir, así que solo tuve que llamar a `crearObservable$()` después de suscribirme:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.datos$ = this.servicio1.getObservable$();
    this.datos$.subscribe(datos => this.datos = datos);
    console.log(this.datos);
    this.servicio1.crearObservable$();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es que creas el subject y emites algo antes de que cualquier observer se haya suscrito, con lo que lo emitido no es observado por nadie.

Quizá deberías usar un `BehaviorSubject`, que emite cuando alguien se suscribe.

Comment: Tu respuesta me ayudado mucho, pero para no rehacer todo he ajustado el código que ya tenia. Gracias.